# which java to install on client machine

Tags: java, deployment

I am confused about installing java to run java applications on client pc. 
I developed a `Java application`. I need to deploy it on a `Windows XP Embedded` client machine. There is no `java` installed on the client side. I verified that by typing "`java`" in command prompt of the client pc. So i realised that i need to install `java`. But which version?
I am a .NET developer and I am a beginner to Java world. I never deploy my Java application on client machines so i am alittle bit confused.
Can you show me the way of installing right `JDK/JRE/Java/etc.` version on `Windows XP Embedded`?
I prefer `offline installation` and `light versions` because my client machine is a mini industrial pc which has no internet access and very limited storage(1 GB).

Comment: That depends on the version of Java in which the app was written. If your app was written in 1.7, then you have to install JRE 1.7+ to execute the app properly.

Comment: @WhoAmI how can i learn which version of Java i developed the application? I am using Netbeans 7.4

Comment: [Here](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.xml) to find java version that you developed. OR type simply command line `javac -version`.

Comment: on the machine where you developed the app, type java -version / javac -verson in the cmd prompt.

Comment: To find the version of Java that you used, go into NetBeans right-click on your project and select properties, then look for the project JDK that you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instal JRE instead of JDK which are generally larger in size.
If you care for space install any older JRE verision which would help you in minimizing the storage space.
Or else you can install latest [JRE 1.8] http://filehippo.com/en/download_jre_32/changelog/
Will take around 44 MB.Do look for your windows bit architecture if it is 32 bit or 64.

Hope this helps.Please accept the answer if it do.

Since i do not have enough reputation to post comment.I am posting it as answer.

Comment: I have jre 1.7 update 55. so i find this [link](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/windows_offline_download.xml) and installed this version. Java web site says that Java 8 is not supported by Windows XP so i didnt download the lastest. Now it works, thanks.